# What's missing in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I think there are not many people who don't think that ASP.NET MVC is one of the greatest technologies Microsoft gave us. It gives full control over the rendered HTML, provides separation of concerns and suits to stateless nature of web.

Next versions of framework gaves us new features and tools and it's great, but... what solutions should Microsoft include in new versions of framework? What are biggest gaps in comparison with another web frameworks like PHP or Ruby? What could improve developers productivity? What's missing in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would love to see better server side validation support. Data Annotations doesn't really cut the mustard.

Also I need a way to properly personalize the validation error message when an invalid format of a nullable property (such as int?, float?, DateTime?, ...) has been entered by the user and the model binder tries to set the value. I am sick of `string` backing properties and manually parsing nullable types.

Also donut caching is a feature that every respected web framework must have built-in support for.

Comment: Darin... can you say something more? What's wrong with them? For me the biggest issue is that there should be much more validator to avoid necessity of writing own one in simple cases like credit card number...

Comment: They pollute the view models. Validation is a cross-cutting concern that needs to be separate. There also must be support for unit testing the validation logic. Something more in the spirit of [FluentValidation.Net](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which is what I currently use. This being said a good progress has been made in ASP.NET MVC 3 with the jquery unobtrusive client side validation support and the dumping of the MS AJAX joke of a framework.

Comment: Completely agreed. Attributes are *ok* for very simple cases, but they're impossible to test, pollute the view model and aren't that flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I would love some more shorthand helpers around routes, similar to what rails has with `:resource` or `:resources` routes for example.

Answer (score 1):

Biggest issue for me are lack of some action result types like XmlActionResult or PdfActionResult.. they could be usefull...

Comment: While I agree for `XmlActionResult`, don't expect a `PdfActionResult` any time soon from Microsoft :-)

Comment: Yeah - unless Microsoft is willing to roll out a Pdf library, which we know won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Built in support for migrations and activerecord